# Understanding Mongoose startup code from the official documentation

Tags: mongoose

I am trying to run the following code from
[official Mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
main().catch(err => console.log(err));

async function main() {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');

  console.log("hello, connection established!");

  // Create a schema
  const kittySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String
  });

  // Create a model
  const Kitten = mongoose.model('Kitten', kittySchema);
  const silence = new Kitten({ name: 'Silence' });
  console.log(silence.name); // 'Silence'

  // Save the document in the Mongo database
  await silence.save();

  // Find all documents
  const res = await Kitten.find();
  console.log(res);
}
```

I don't see any output when I run this program `node this_program.js`
Is there something I am missing ?

Comment: Recent versions of the MongoDB driver (which Mongoose uses) don't like it when you use `localhost` as server address; instead, try `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Thank you, I tried `127.0.0.1` and it gives me some output however  I don't get the command prompt back. It just sort of hangs

Comment: As long as you keep the connection open Node.js will not exit. Try adding `mongoose.connection.close()` after the last `console.log()`.